# how to put random colors in chart js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a service that returns random colors, the idea is that each query returns a color x , and that the lines are different to differentiate them.

This is the part of the code where I handle the color.

```js
const color = this.helpersService.randomColor()
const datasets = Object.keys(this.aux).map(key => ({
  label: key,
  backgroundColor: color,
  borderColor: color,
  fill: false,
  data: this.aux[key].map((item) => item.monto_moneda_norm)
}));
```

[image: Grafico]

Comment: Can you not call `this.helpersService.randomColor()` for each item instead of one time up front?

Comment: I think that's the idea, but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: `const color = this.helpersService.randomColor()` inside the loop then return the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
const randomColor = (i) => {
  const colors = ["#93B5C6", "#DDEDAA", "#F0CF65", "#D7816A", "#BD4F6C"];
  return colors[i % colors.length];
}

const datasets = Object.keys(this.aux).map((key, index) => {
  const color = randomColor(index);
  return {
    label: key,
    backgroundColor: color,
    borderColor: color,
    fill: false,
    data: this.aux[key].map((item) => item.monto_moneda_norm)
  };
});
```

There is also a plugin: https://github.com/kurkle/chartjs-plugin-autocolors